# Migrating WPMS from apache to IIS7 causes Database Error

Tags: multisite, database, migration, apache, iis

### *// Be sure to read the updates at the bottom*

I have a large multisite installation hosted on XAMPP on an XP 2003 server and am trying to move it from XAMPP/Apache to a new Windows 2008 server with IIS7.

I can successfully get fresh installs of WP up and running and can get multisite working perfectly. When I import my old WPMS MySQL database and change the `DB_NAME` in my `wp-config.php` file to have the old WPMS database instead of the new WPMS database, I'm hit with "Error establishing database connection"

Here are my `wp-config.php` settings:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'migrated_DB_2012');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wpms_user_2012');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'wpms_password');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

I've double checked the username & password and even changed them several times to make sure they matched up. I've tried `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and the IP address of my server itself for the DB_NAME. Nothing.

---

### */* UPDATE */*

I've successfully connected to the database finally!

Visiting the front page of the domain (http://domain.com) gave me the **Error establishing database connection** message, but trying to visit the dashboard/admin area (http://domain.com/wp-admin) helped me see the problem. In my many DB/user name changes, I neglected to give full permissions to `wpms_user_2012` on `migrated_DB_2012`. **D'OH!**

#### // New Problem


I still get the database error when visiting the front page, but now when I visit  `/wp-admin`, I see the following:

> *One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.*

When I follow the "repair" link, it walks me through the auto-repair sequence, but since this is a multisite installation, it skips over a few tables and tells me the following tables don't exist:

- wp_posts
- wp_comments
- wp_links
- wp_options
- wp_postmeta
- wp_terms
- wp_term_taxonomy
- wp_term_relationships
- wp_commentmeta

Only, these tables **do** exist, but they exist as: `wp_1_posts`, `wp_1_comments`, etc.

What should the next steps be to get my migrated DB to work properly?

---

### */* Let me explain a little more */*

For this installation, I started from scratch with a fresh install of WP, set it up with a network and then copied the old `/blogs.dir` over to the new `wp-content/`.

*(Reasoning for fresh install: I believe my old site had been hacked and I wanted to prevent any compromised core files from being transferred over to the new server.)*

Next, I imported my old database (`migrated_WPMS_database`) into MySQL via phpMyAdmin, gave the appropriate privileges to the `wpms_user` and set up `wp-config.php` with the proper database/user/password information.

I ran the WP repair and you can see my **// Update** for the results. Basically, it was telling me that the main site's tables weren't there: I've read that the "repair" feature doesn't work well with WPMS because it looks for `wp_[tableNames]` instead of `wp_1_[tableNames]`. Am I mistaken?

After this, I even went through phpMyAdmin and ran it's built in "repair", also.

I can still connect successfully to the fresh install's database (`test_database`) if I change `wp-config.php` accordingly. So, it **is** seeing that it is a network and it **is** able to connect to the database server successfully, too.

Based on the WP Repair results, it seems WP is still looking for `wp_[tableNames]` instead of `wp_1_[tableNames]`, is that right? Why would it do this? There's got to be something I'm missing inside the migrated database's tables or something, because of the message I receive when trying to access `wp-admin`:

> *One or more database tables are unavailable. The database may need to be repaired.*

If it helps, my OLD site was set up as WPMU back before the merge, so the OLD `wp-config.php` is set up slightly different, and if I use it instead of the newer 3.3 `wp-config.php`, my front-end becomes a blank screen and I'm able to get to the wp-login screen ... but it just puts me into a redirect loop back to the login page.

Comment: Are you sure you migrated *everything* properly? Including `wp-config.php`?  This sounds like a case of WP thinking it's still a single-site installation.

Comment: My old site had some hacked files in there somewhere. So I was trying to prevent this bad code from coming over to the new server. I created a fresh install, set it up as a network, then moved the old site's `wp-contents` folder to the new server and imported the old database. So, there was a new `wp-config` file created. I was successfully connecting to the database, but it was telling me that there some of the tables weren't there: I've read that the "repair" feature doesn't work well with WPMS because it looks for the `wp_[tableNames]` instead of `wp_1_[tableNames]`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @EAMann, I added more explanation to my question.

Comment: So the old site was the exact same version as the new site? "my OLD site was set up as WPMU back before the merge" doesn't make this very clear.

Comment: @EAMann, yes, the WP versions are the same (3.3). I'm just saying that the files look _slightly_ different since I started with MU before 3.0. Here are the wp-config files: [Old WPMU 3.3 based wp-config.php](http://pastebin.com/3UsR8WeV) & [New WPMS 3.3 based wp-config.php](http://pastebin.com/sFbdHUCX). They're  both WPMS now, but I'm using MU & MS to differentiate between the two. Still basically the same, just a few things have changed. Like, the old file used `define('VHOST', 'no');` to say to use subdirectories & not subdomains. New version uses `define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked through this problem myself with the help of a forum mod on [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org). You can [see the full forum post here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/migrating-wpms-from-apache-to-iis7-causes-database-error?replies=22).