# Media Library won't recognize SOME old files after move

Tags: database, media-library, iis

First off, I'm on a **Windows 2008** box running **IIS7** with a `web.config` file not `htaccess`.

That being said, I've [migrated my old Apache(XAMPP) installed WPMS site over to a new IIS7 server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48036/migrating-wpms-from-apache-to-iis7-causes-database-error) successfully with one glitch: my media files are doing some really funky stuff.

**// The run down:**
I have my main site and about 200+ subsites. Uploading new files to the `blogs.dir` folder is successful and I'm able to see them on my site just fine afterwards.

**// The funk:**
*SOME* of my old files (PDF and Word documents) on my main site are still linked properly. It seems to be only pre-move image files that are affected. The files are still listed in the media library correctly and I can see the files in the directories themselves, but there is a disconnect between the Library and the directories.

***Caveat:*** I've had to keep my main site's upload folder set to `/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/` because my WordPress installation was pre-3.0. This hasn't shown itself to be an issue yet, since I can still see some of the files and I can upload new files. I tried moving it to `/wp-content/uploads/`, but that seemed to give me more of a headache.

[Here is my web.config file](http://pastebin.com/H3fWApD7) in case someone is able to see some issue within it that's causing the problem.

*Any* help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's the [wordpress.org forum thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/media-library-wont-recognize-some-old-files-after-move?replies=15) of me working through it.